# Slash in Dancer token

Tags: perl, dancer

I would like to interpret, for example a request like this:

```
GET /my/path?foo=bar
```

just as if it was actually rewritten to e.g.

```
GET /?path=/my/path&foo=bar
```

---

Now I thought I'll be able to achieve this using following route, and use `param('path')` along with `param('foo')` and the likes, e.g.:

```
get '/:path' => sub {
    return printf "...so you want %s, thinking that best foo is %s...",
        param('path'),
        param('foo');
}
```

but I get 404 -- It seems that the `:path` part cannot contain slashes.

Can I achieve this with routes at all?  Or I'm looking at the wrong direction (I'm fresh new to Dancer)?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to match route by regular expression instead of the token.  Matches are then stored in a special array that can be returned by keyword `splat`.  Your `path` will not be accessible by `param('path')`, though.

Code:

```
get qr{/([^?]*)} => sub {
    my ($path) = splat;
    return printf "...so you want %s, thinking that best foo is %s...",
        $path,
        param('foo');
}
```

Comment: This (as well as use of wildcards), unfortunately, introduces an issue that `splat` key with the matches will be inadvertently added to the params() space, which would be problem if you *really* want to pass e.g. `splat=splosh` via GET query.  See [my post to Dancer users' mailing list](http://lists.preshweb.co.uk/pipermail/dancer-users/2012-December/002858.html)